# 32x32 icons for rich text editor?

Tags: html, richtextediting

Does anybody know a open source/free, 32x32 or bigger, complete set of "office" icons for integration in a Rich Text editor - i.e. buttons like

- Copy
- Paste
- Text color
- Background color
- Bold / Italic / Underline

?

Comment: Just in case anyone ran into this searching for formatting icons line bold, italic, underline etc for their web application (as I was doing). Fontawesome does hold a lot of these icons. (However, it is not a full solution like the other ones mentioned).

Comment: I was also looking for similar icons but in Material Design (Paper)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look into the **[Tango Icon Library](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library)**, it looks great and it's into the public domain (as noted in their [FAQ](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions)).

The have the same icons in 16x16, 32x32 and 64x64 but they also gave you the svg source, so, you can easily get any dimensions you want exporting them with **[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org)**

You can also use the LGPL **[Crystal Clear](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear)**  as recommended by **[cobbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73681/cobbal)**.

Comment: Cheers, I didn't realize Tango comes with the source. I think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hope that it serves you well!.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear

Comment: Good icons but they don't have a full set of the standard office icons I need - copy, paste, bold, italic, underline....

Answer (score 3):

**32x32 or Larger**

1. [The Best Vector Icon Sets All In One Place](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/the-best-vector-icon-sets-all-in-one-place)
2. [21 Best Icon Sets for Designing Web Apps](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/21-best-icon-sets-for-designing-web-apps)

On `2` I think this one might be what you want: [WeFunction Free Icon Set](http://wefunction.com/2008/07/function-free-icon-set/)

**16x16 Icons**

You should be able to find icons to suit your needs here. I use this page as a reference all the time when looking for little icons:

[All the Small Icons You’ll Ever Need](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/all-the-small-icons-youll-ever-need)  by the Web Design Ledger

Comment: @Pekka, my brain shorted out. I updated my question with two more links, but the "WeFunction Free Icon Set" might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Ooh, the function ones look great, I will definitely be using some of those. Cheers!...

Answer (score 3):

another great one that is not listed.
http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/ is a free icon set with 3160 icons atm. they are 16x16 and some are animated gifs.

Answer (score 1):

Some one in my team uses [this](http://icofx.ro/). Ico fx. I have never used it my self but the icons always look good.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is non-commercial, then look at this nice [spherical Icon set](http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/the-spherical-2230/).

If your project is commercial, I'd suggest that a hundred bucks or so would be a good investment :-) eg. something from the [Text bundle at IconShock](http://www.iconshock.com/icon-collections/toolbar-icons-full-text-icons.html).